# Why does source operate with char?

Tags: scala, io

I'm new to Scala and would like to use `scala.io.Source` class. But I found out that it operates with `Char`s, but not `Byte`s. The thing that I'm confused about is that `Char`s are encoding/platform dependent. I mean we can have characters encoded in `UTF-8` or "windows-1251".

`windows-1251` is strictly 1-byte encoding... Is there a way to operate with raw bytes?

Comment: `Char`s in Scala are UTF-16 and are not platform dependent.

Comment: @n.m. even worse. I have strings windows-1251 encoded. So `scala.io.Source` is not applicable?

Comment: Source is Char-oriented and so is for text data. If you want to operate on text data, scala.io.Source is a good choice. If you want a binary stream, consider using java's InputStream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to read `Char` as `windows-1251`, you can do it like:

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile(myFile, "windows-1251")
```

set **encoding** for this read.